# where в запросе при объединении полей

Tags: mysql

прошу подсказать

```
//объединяем 3 поля - работает
SELECT concat(`t1`.`a`, ', ', `t1`.`b`, ' ', `t1`.`c`) as `rrr`
FROM `adress` as `t1`
WHERE 1

//пытаюсь что то найти - не работает, неизвестное поле 'rrr'
SELECT concat(`t1`.`a`, ', ', `t1`.`b`, ' ', `t1`.`c`) as `rrr`
FROM `adress` as `t1`
WHERE `rrr`='Павловский Посад, Московская обл'
```

Подскажите, почему поле, которое я обозначил в запросе не видно?

p.s.

```
//так ищет, я так понял, я что то не знаю про concat()
SELECT `t1`.`a` as `rrr`
FROM `adress` as `t1`
WHERE `rrr`='Павловский Посад'
```

Comment: Поле выходного набора не существует на момент выполнения WHERE. Или переносите конкатенацию в CTE/подзапрос, или. если сервер разрешит, используйте HAVING, или дублируйте выражение во WHERE.

Comment: Порядок выполнения разный: сначала WHERE, потом SELECT. Поменяйте WHERE на [HAVING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).